# Method not defined on grpc Client

Tags: node.js, grpc

I'm working on my first grpc service and I am unable to get the most basic method working.

Here is my server code:

```
const grpc = require('grpc');
const ipvalid_proto = grpc.load('ip_valid.proto').ipvalid;
const server = new grpc.Server();
server.addService(ipvalid_proto.IPValidator.service, {
  IsIPValid:(arg, callback) => callback(null, true),
});
server.bind('127.0.0.1:50051', grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure());
server.start();
```

And my client looks like this:

```
const grpc = require('grpc');
const ipvalid_proto = grpc.load('ip_valid.proto').ipvalid;
const client = new ipvalid_proto.IPValidator('localhost:50051', grpc.credentials.createInsecure());  
client.IsIPValid({ address: '127.0.0.1' }, (err, res) => {});
```

I start the server first, and then the client and I always get:

> client.IsIPValid is not a function

in the logging of the client. What do I have wrong here? It looks exactly like the basic examples provided in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generated Node.js gRPC clients change method names to `camelCase` to match the established JS style for method names. So, in this case, the client object should have the method `isIPValid` (note the starting lowercase 'I').

Note: This is a point of confusion that has been reported more than a few times, and it's something we will look at improving.